# how can I read a file to an char array instead of using readline in java

Tags: java, ram, readfile

I'm trying to read a huge file and put them into a Hash. I'm having a lot of problems because of my small size of RAM. I'm reading the file line by line and I read somewhere it would be much better if I read the whole file in a char array and then read from there line by line. How can I do this?

the format of the file is something like

```
1 3
4 6
3 9
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Storing a Huge file in memory will consume huge quantities of ram. Instead of using a in memory Hash, you should look at a disk alternative (one of SQL Data Base, Index file (e.g. Berkley) or a No Sql DB)

Comment: It will not help in memory usage, but, to read the file in one go you can use `Properties` class `load()` API. This way you will not have to write your own code to process lines http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29

Answer (score 1):

A `char` array is still stored in RAM.  You're already using less RAM by processing the file line by line.  The only option to avoid storing the file in memory is to memory map it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html